# Are the buttons for selecting the order of the answers clear enough?

Tags: feature-request, design

I just recently saw the buttons (active, oldest, votes) on the askubuntu.com website and realized that I didn't recall seeing them on TeX.SE. Presumably they were there for a while, but I simply didn't seem them. This leads me to the obvious question:

> Are these buttons clear enough?

if not, perhaps we should think about modifying their design so that they are still unobtrusive, but not as obscure as I find them to be.

---

EDIT: there seems to be some confusion as to what buttons I'm referring to (probably corroborating the fact that they are obscure...) so here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a possible design option for the buttons that we already use! in the user profile page:

[image]

I think that this design is much more clear and yet still unobtrusive.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the main issue you have with those is that they don't really look like buttons, but more like a text label or link. On askubuntu.com they have a more button-like look (see screenshot), with shades and are visually distinct from the remainder of the layout.

[image: Ubuntu question sort buttons]

That being said, I don't see any (big) problem with that, but I guess it's just me being used to the design of TeX.SE and the general layout of SE sites.

Comment: I think Yossi is not talking about _those_ links, but about "active oldest votes" that appears right to "<n> Answer(s)". (I use these links from time to time and had no trouble finding them.)